# É melhor usar divisão comum ou operações Shift e Soma em microcontroladores 8bits

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, otimização, microcontroladores-8bits

Considerando programação para microcontroladores 8bits, sabemos que mesmo par este microcontroladores, os compiladores atingiram um nível de otimização singular e que nos permite programar focado apenas na qualidade da leitura do código.

Porém quando se programa para microcontroladores é fundamental que nos preocupemos sempre com o desempenho de nosso código e com seu tamanho.

Diante disso é melhor usar operações matemáticas complexas para o processador como a divisão, ou partirmos diretamente para uma otimização do código e usarmos operadores lógicos para deslocamento (shift) e somas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teria de saber

a) o modelo exato do processador, bem como a versão do mesmo, porque diferentes versões com o mesmo instruction set podem ter performance bem diferente na instrução de divisão. E muitas arquiteturas nem têm instrução de divisão (8051 tem, AVR não tem).

b) qual o tipo de divisão que seu código vai enfrentar mais. Divisão por potência de 2? Divisão por uma constante? A constante é pequena, tipo 3, 5, 7?

Mesmo em arquiteturas "gordas" como x86, um bom compilador substitui a instrução DIV por multiplicações, somas e shifts, como a célebre divisão por 3:

```
return (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)0xAAAAAAABULL * divideMe) >> 33);
```

mas isso vale a pena quando se trata de um divisor constante e pequeno. O DIV de um processador é otimizado para o "caso médio", ou seja, ele vai ter performance melhor que divisão por software se considerar todos os divisores possíveis.

Um outro problema que aparece quando se tenta fazer divisão (ou multiplicação) usando instruções mais elementares é a questão de como lidar com o sinal (positivo ou negativo).